# Shorten String function not working properly

Tags: php, function

I have this little function to stop a string being too long but it dosen't seem to work. I'm assuming i've done something wrong?

```
function trimString($string, $maxChar) {
   $string = (strlen($string) > $maxChar) ? substr($string,0,$maxChar).'...' : $string;
}
```

I was using it like this:

```
echo trimString($row['mainTitle'], 30);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return value from function. Try

```
function trimString($string, $maxChar) {
   return (strlen($string) > $maxChar) ? substr($string,0,$maxChar).'...' : $string;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! knew i forgot something. Working now.